# Having count(distinct x) not returning correct results - Teradata SQL

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

I'm working in Teradata, and my data looks like this:

[Image of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pEE7.png)
my query is:

```
select id, type
from table1
where id in (100, 101)
group by 1,2
having count(distinct type) > 1
```

but its returning nothing??? I'm confused why it's not working. I'm expecting it to return where the distinct type is greater than 1, so shouldn't the output be???:

[Image of expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0L0uA.png)

Please help

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) and [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055) both apply here.

Comment: You are grouping by type and then doing count distinct on it.  It will never be anything other than 1.  Can't see your images, but maybe you mean to be counting a different column?

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct id, type
from table1
where id in (100, 101)
```

Comment: this doesn't work as there are other columns which make the data distinct. I have edited to reflect what I mean

Answer (score 0):

One option is to first find `ID` value(s) that satisfy the condition, and then - using that query as a subquery - extract other columns you're interested in. As you want only one comment per `[ID, TYPE]` combination, use one of aggregation functions, such as `MIN` or `MAX`.

```
SQL> select id, type, min(comments) comments
  2  from table1
  3  where id in (select id
  4               from table1
  5               where id in (100, 101)
  6               group by id
  7               having count(distinct type) > 1
  8              )
  9  group by id, type;

        ID TYPE   COMMENTS
---------- ------ ---------------
       100 Honda  This is a large
       100 Toyota Yr 1990

SQL>
```